# TypeError: from_formula() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, anova

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./data1/avg_quations.xlsx')

dataset=df.values

#print ( df)

print (df.groupby('TARGETS').mean())

lm = ols('TARGETS~AVRAGE' , dataset=dataset).FIT()

aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(lm, typ=2)

print(aov_table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter provided to `ols` should be `data`, not `dataset`, i.e.:

```
lm = ols('TARGETS~AVRAGE' , data=dataset).FIT()
```

Alternatively, you could pass this as a positional argument:

```
lm = ols('TARGETS~AVRAGE' , dataset).FIT()
```

Comment: This error it solved ,but this error is show(PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
    TARGETS~AVRAGE)
            ^^^^^^

Comment: Are you sure that `AVRAGE` is the name of the column, not `AVERAGE`?